# BITCOIN SCRIPT: Write the bitcoin ScriptPubKey script for a transaction that can be redeemed by anybody who supplies a square root of 1764?

Tags: blockchain, cryptography

Bitcoin script: For the following questions, you're free to use non-standard transactions and op codes that are currently disabled. You can use as a shorthand to represent data values pushed onto the stack. For a quick reference, see here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script a. Write the Bitcoin ScriptPubKey script for a transaction that can be redeemed by anybody who supplies a square root of 1764. Write a corresponding ScriptSig script to redeem your transaction. Suppose you wanted to issue a new RSA factoring challenge by publishing a transaction that can be redeemed by anybody who can factor a 1024-bit RSA number (RSA numbers are the product of two large, secret prime numbers). What difficulties might you run into?

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework.  At least, it seems to have been taken from another source without attribution.  Please state the source.

Comment: There’s no secure way of doing that anyway. The funds can be stolen while unconfirmed and you can do nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
decodescript 769502e40687
{
  "asm": "OP_DUP OP_MUL 1764 OP_EQUAL",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "3JQspThZ3pAdZZjUfb6hni5f8rW9yYonJv"
}
```

https://bchsvexplorer.com/address/3JQspThZ3pAdZZjUfb6hni5f8rW9yYonJv

Comment: Shorter: 012a87. Neither is a meaningful script of course, but they have the same semantics.

Comment: @Pieter, isn't it a Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything? :)))))